# Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::_addLeft() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Block_Abstract, boolean given

Tags: magento-1.9, php, error, blocks

What does this error mean and how can I fix it? I'm sure it is related to me upgrading to php7. Thanks

Error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::_addLeft() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Block_Abstract, boolean given, called in controllers/Adminhtml/ListController.php on line 29 and defined in Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php:63
```

From ListController.php:

```
        public function editAction()
        {
            $id     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $model  = Mage::getModel('commentbox/comment')->load($id);
            if ($model->getId() || $id == 0)
            {
                $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
                if (!empty($data))
                    $model->setData($data);

                Mage::register('comment_data', $model);
                $this->loadLayout();
                $this->_setActiveMenu('system/commentbox');
                $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('commentbox/adminhtml_list_edit'))
  line 29-->         ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('commentbox/adminhtml_list_edit_tabs'));
                $this->renderLayout();
            }
            else
            {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('commentbox')->__('Specified Script was not found!'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            }
        }
```

From Action.php:

```
line 63-->   protected function _addLeft(Mage_Core_Block_Abstract $block)
    {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('left')->append($block);
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: are you sure the class with alias "commentbox/adminhtml_list_edit_tabs" exists?

Comment: Not sure if I have the class. How can I find out? I have this folder structure: Block/Adminhtml/List/Edit/Form.php

Comment: Do you have the file `[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/List/Edit/Tabs.php`

Comment: No I don't. Strange. It use to work.

Comment: Firstly, Magento 1.x doesn't support PHP7 so you're probably wasting your time

Comment: @Robbie Yes I'm running php7 on my magento using Inchoo_PHP7 module. It makes my site faster. Works very good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments...
The error appears because the block invoked `[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/List/Edit/Tabs.php` does not exist.
In this case the `createBlock` method returns `false` and the `_addLeft` method gives an error because it expects an object as parameter not a boolean value.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't fix that. So I deleted it. Thanks